# iphone: Hands free gestures

Tags: detect, face-detection, feature-detection, uitapgesturerecognizer, motion-detection

In my iPhone app, I require to recognize the gesture or motion made by the user on the view without touching it.

I want the hand free gestures to be recognized and perform a function on view.

I need that the image should move with the gesture detection.

What needs to be done?

How do I recognize it?

Any directions or tutorials will be really appreciated.

Comment: What are you thinking about? Even though it is pretty close iOS still can't perform any magic. Do you want to use the camera?

Comment: it is possible, but how? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is there any leap motion for ios/iphone?                                       Please suggest me or help me!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at OpenCV. There is a good example on how to use OpenCV to recognize a hand here: http://www.andol.info/hci/1661.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                                                 Can it be available for ios platform. So that i can check.